# Proof of the equality of the difference of two sets iff sets are equal (direct vs. indirect)

Tags: elementary-set-theory, alternative-proof

I have a problem with the following (really) basic result:
$$A\backslash B=B\backslash A \Longleftrightarrow A=B$$

More specifically, I am able to prove it only by contradiction (in particular in the necessary condition - for the sufficient condition I get a contradiction following the steps of a direct proof).

So my problem is, can we actually prove it without using contradiction?
Moreover (and this is probably a very dumb question, so I apologize), is there a general way to know if a given result that we know is true can be proven only by contradiction or there exist a direct proof of it?

Looking forward to any feedback!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose that $A\setminus B=B\setminus A$. Since $B\setminus A\subseteq B$, this implies that $A\setminus B\subseteq B$. But $(A\setminus B)\cap B=\varnothing$, so $A\setminus B=\varnothing$, and it follows immediately that $A\subseteq B$. Similarly, $B\subseteq A$, so $A=B$.

I suspect that you didn’t really use a proof by contradiction, however: more likely you found a proof of the contrapositive and dressed it up as a proof by contradiction. The contrapositive of this implication is that if $A\ne B$, then $A\setminus B\ne B\setminus A$. If $A\ne B$, then without loss of generality there is some $x\in A\setminus B$ that is not in $B\setminus A$. But then $x\in A$ and $x\notin B$, so $A\ne B$. If you began by assuming that $A=B$, this is a proof by contradiction, but that assumption is unnecessary: without it you have a direct proof of the contrapositive of the original implication.

Comment: For $\Longrightarrow$ I start by assuming $A\backslash B = B \backslash A$. Then I take an arbitrary element, and I assume it is an element of $A$. Then I assume that this element is not an element of $B$. Thus, I get the contradiction.

Comment: @Kolmin: Okay; my guess at how you got your contradiction was wrong. Note that proving the contrapositive does in any case give you another way to avoid contradiction if you really want to, though I don’t myself see any reason to care.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I don't follow your first few steps - you say that $A \backslash B \subset B$ however, that doesn't seem to be true from the statement you previously stated O.o

Comment: @Kolmin: By the way, you could use the same starting point to get a different contradiction. If $a\in A$, then $a\notin B\setminus A$, so $a\notin A\setminus B\subseteq A$.

Comment: @Dan: You’re applying the $X,Y$ statement to the wrong thing: $$A\setminus B=B\setminus A\subseteq B\;.$$

Comment: Ah ok, was a bit misleading I apologize!

Comment: @Dan: No problem. I’ve changed the general statement to the specific one required in hopes of making it clearer.

Answer (score 4):

$\Rightarrow$

Let $a \in A$. We want to prove $a\in B$

If $a \in B$ we're done.

If $a\not\in B$ then $a \in A \setminus B$ so $a\in B\setminus A \subseteq B$ so $a\in B$

So $A\subseteq B$

Similarly $B\subseteq A$

So $A=B$

---

$\Leftarrow$

Suppose $A=B$

$A\setminus B = \emptyset = B\setminus A$

Answer (score 3):

Here is a direct proof:

Take any element $a\in A$.  We know that $a\notin B\setminus A=A\setminus B$, so $a\in B$.  It follows that $A\subset B$.  The reverse containment is similar.

Comment: Actually, this is an interesting proof for me, because I don't see for the $\Longrightarrow$ part how can we say something about $B$. Indeed, it looks to me that to use the biconditional about the differences, we need to know something about $B$... Something I get using contradiction (see my proof below Brian M. Scott's post).

Comment: @Kolmin: If $a\in A$, then $a\notin B\setminus A$.  If $a\notin B\setminus A$, then $a\notin A\setminus B$, because $B\setminus A=A\setminus B$.  If $a\notin A\setminus B$, then $a\in B$.  So $A\subset B$.  There is no contradiction here.

Comment: "If $a\in A$, then $a \not \in B\backslash A$"... here there is what I was missing (quite bad actually). Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some another proof. Basically, it uses the fact that $(p \iff q) \iff [(p \wedge q)\vee(\neg p \wedge \neg q)]$.
\begin{align}
A\setminus B = B \setminus A &\iff [x \in A \setminus B \iff x \in B \setminus A]\\
&\iff [(x \in A \setminus B \wedge x \in B \setminus A) \vee (x \not\in A \setminus B \wedge x \not\in B \setminus A)]\\
&\iff [0 \vee (x \in A \wedge x \in B) \vee (x \not\in A \wedge x \not\in B)]\\
&\iff [x \in A \iff x \in B]\\
&\iff A = B.
\end{align}

Comment: Fun fact: note that the parentheses in $(\dots \iff \dots) \iff \dots$ are not necessary.

Comment: However, your parentheses are still useful to prevent ambiguity: In your second use of $P \iff Q \iff R \iff \dots$, you actually mean $(P \iff Q) \land (Q \iff R) \land \dots$, but in your first use you _do_ mean $P \iff Q \iff R$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the beginning of a proof, using the definition $$x \in A \setminus B \;\equiv\; x \in A \land \lnot(x \in B)$$  Let's just start at the most complex side, the left hand side, and see if we can simplify it at the logic/element level:
$$
\begin{align}
& A \setminus B \;=\; B \setminus A \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"extensionality, i.e., two sets are equal iff they have the same elements"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \setminus B \;\equiv\; x \in B \setminus A \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"definition of $\setminus$, twice"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: x \in A \land \lnot(x \in B) \;\equiv\; x \in B \land \lnot(x \in A) \rangle \\
\equiv & \;\;\;\;\;\text{"negate one side using De Morgan -- to use the Golden Rule (see below)"} \\
& \langle \forall x :: \lnot(x \in A \land \lnot(x \in B) \;\equiv\; \lnot(x \in B) \lor x \in A)) \rangle \\
\end{align}
$$
Now apply (what Dijkstra/Gries/etc. call) the Golden Rule, viz. $$P \;\equiv\; Q \;\equiv\; P \land Q \;\equiv\; P \lor Q$$ for every boolean expression $P$ and $Q$.